# Digital third eye using two Android devices: viewing live-camera from one device on a second device

Tags: android, video, real-time

Some times I would like to show the camera live view recorded by one Android device on the second Android device, so that the first device acts as a "digital third eye".

This would be especially useful e.g. to look in detail at the skin on your back when you are alone (or you don't want to ask somebody for help).

So I am searching an Android app that allows to **send the live camera image from one device to a second device** which also runs the same app. The **data transmission should be direct**, best P2P **without requiring any external network** like Wifi or cellular (for data privacy). Best would be something like a connection using Android Direct Wifi.

As both devices are always kept close to each other I don't care about audio transmission. For me only the video data is relevant.

Does anybody know such an app?

Preferred open source to make sure that the camera pictures are not stored and uploaded to a service, but closed source or low price paid apps would also be acceptable.

Comment: Not sure which app fully meets your requirements – but some of those in my category for [Streaming](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_streaming) between 2 Android devices might fit. Be welcome to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) if a good candidate is among those :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Izzy's Android [list of apps that allow streaming between two devices](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_streaming) I extracted the following interesting open source projects (not yet tested):

#### [Remote Video Camera](https://github.com/izivkov/RemoteVideoCam)

- Project is still alive
- Does not support Wifi-Direct
- MIT License according to F-Droid (no license info found in Github project)

#### [Endoscope](https://github.com/hypeapps/Endoscope)

- Project is no longer supported since 2018
- GPL-3.0 license

#### [Kage - Cast multimedia content to Other devices](https://github.com/zhaobozhen/Kage)

- App was just a graduation project
- Discontinued in 2020
- Apache 2.0 license